# Regex jupyter notebook

Tags: python, regex, jupyter

I need your help in building a regex expression in Jupyter notebook.
I have a column with US addresses in a data frame.
And some of the streets have a single letter at the beginning:

W SUNSET BLVD

S VERMONT AVE

N VINE ST

E 59TH ST

WILSHIRE BLVD

BEVERLY BLVD

How do I get rid of those single letters at the beginning of a street name with a regex expression?
I have built this, but it doesn't work:

**rest_data['street_name'] = rest_data['street_name'].replace('^[NESW]\s','',regex=True)**

Could you please help me fix this? Or maybe replace it with something better?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The regex works at https://regex101.com/r/oxRTUQ/1. Just click the Code Generator button on the left to see an example of proper Python code.

Comment: yeah, but for some reason in Jupyter, nothing changes with the street names, I get the same "W SUNSET BLVD" when select data from that column after the replace mentioned above. So something must be wrong, I just have no idea what

Comment: I'm really not familiar with Jupyter. Can you provide a link to the docs which show the usage of `.replace()`?

Comment: If you are accessing your data from a database or a file the change will not reflect there. You have to save the changes as well.

Comment: I second what @lkdhruw said. The code you've shown manipulates data in memory. You may need to issue another command to save the data back to the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex is correctly picking up , but not replacing. You may have misplaced the parameters in the replace method.

Here is the syntax from the official website:

```
DataFrame.replace(to_replace=None, value=None, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method='pad')
```

I think your code should be replaced by the following :

```
 rest_data['street_names'] = rest_data['street_names'].replace(to_replace="^\s[NEWS]\s", value='', regex=True)
```

It Worked For Me:

I Just assumed after removing numbers and symbols the string may have white space in front so a little correction to the regex did the trick.

[Latest_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVxgK.png)

Comment: copied your line as it is and it didn't work, I don't know what to think - https://ibb.co/JpqjK82

Comment: sure, here you can find some sample data in the csv file + my code and comments in the .html - https://ufile.io/f/i61yd
PS thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tanya In your `test_file.csv`, the column that qualifies is called `address_no_num`. Try `df['address_no_num'].str.replace(r'^[NEWS]\s', '')`

Comment: @Tanya see my answer , i have edited it according to the new code

Comment: @cr4zyc0der, yes, it worked! Huuuuge thank you and have a great day, mate :)